# Incorrect Date Tooltip Line Plus Bar Chart nvd3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm a newbie at using nvd3 charts.

I just copied the javascript code from nvd3 site itself and then add the following html

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
<link href="charts-d3/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"><svg style="height: 500px;"></svg>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="charts-d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="charts-d3/nv.d3.js"></script>
</body>
```

The chart is working and it displays the chart with the data provided by nvd3

but for some reason when i hover to the chart the date of the tooltip always displays 12/31/1969

[Line Plus bar chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uJzx.jpg)

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wLcm3nn9/

Comment: please add a fiddle

Comment: I already added a jsfiddle thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be either a bug in newer versions of nv.d3.js or the example is not updated. The example is using d3.v2.js and version 1.1.11b of nv.d3.js. If you change the script references in the jsfiddle to this:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/novus/nvd3/v1.1.10-beta/nv.d3.js"></script>
```

Then the tooltip should work (although the chart size is not correct)

Updated JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andersaa/xgcj2gw6/1/

Edit: the example seems to be updated to newer libraries and is working in master on github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/novus/nvd3/master/examples/linePlusBarChart.html